# Multiple pack expansions inside class with fixed number of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is this code well-formed? The declaration of the function template itself gives an error in both clang and gcc even though `Ts` could well be empty.

```c++
// error: too many template arguments for class template 'pair'
template<class I, class U, class... Ts>
void f(std::pair<I,U,Ts...>);

int main()
{
    f(std::pair<int,int>());
}
```

The function call gives this error in gcc which doesn't make sense. There is no conversion to `int`:

```c++
note: cannot convert 'std::pair<int, int>()' (type 'std::pair<int, int>') to type 'int'
```

Comment: Try std::tuple instead of std::pair when using more then 2 args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[temp.res]/8:

> If every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty
>   template parameter pack, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

Every valid specialization of `f` would require `Ts` to be an empty pack. Therefore the program is ill-formed NDR. Both compilers are correct.

As to GCC's diagnostic, that seems to be due to its habit of using `int` as a placeholder for "something that looks like a type but doesn't make sense" for error recovery purposes.